# Dimension of vector space of matrices simltaneously diagonalizable with A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a $55 \times 55$ diagonal matrix with characteristic polynomial
$(x - c_1)(x - c_2)^2(x - c_3)^3\cdots(x - c_{10})^{10} $
where $c_1,\cdots,c_{10}$ are all distinct. Let $V$ be the vector space of all $55 \times 55$ matrices $B$
such that $AB = BA$. What is the dimension of $V$ ?

Try:

Since $A$ is given to be diagonal matrix and $AB = BA \implies A$ and $B$ share same eigenbasis, hence are simultaneously diagonalizable. $\exists\, P$ non singular such that  $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ are diagonal. Using the map $f:V \rightarrow A$ as $f(B)=P^{-1}BP \quad \forall B\in V$, we get dimension of $V$ as 10.

Comment: In the worst case, try a coordinate-ful proof. Let $A=\operatorname{diag}(c_1,c_2,c_2,c_3,c_3,c_3,\ldots,c_{10})$ and partition $B$ into a block matrix. If $AB=BA$, what do the sub-blocks of $B$ look like?

Comment: But would partitioning not make it a little messy ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Let $A=c_1I_1\oplus c_2I_2\oplus\cdots\oplus c_{10}I_{10}$. Partition $B$ as a $10\times10$ block matrix with conforming partition to $A$, so that the $k$-th diagonal sub-block of $B$ is $k\times k$ and the size of the $(i,j)$-th sub-block, denoted by $B_{ij}$, is $i\times j$. The equation $AB=BA$ then puts some constraints on each $B_{ij}$.